# Verify the change in element ids of website using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am wondering how to implement a test with C# and Selenium , that checks if an element is existing and whether its id has been changed. All page elements' current Ids and XPaths have been gathered at this stage. I wonder if we are able to track an element ID with its XPath.

For example:

A radio button currently having ID ("Multi") , XPath (//div//...)

After this ID has been changed , the test should be able to show:

ID ("Multi") has been modified , new ID:("MultiType")...  and save this log to a text file.

Any suggestions and hints will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to

1. Fetch the `RadioButton` with `ID` as `Multi`.
2. Save its Absolute XPath, i.e complete Xpath from the Root element. (or just save the complete hierarchy from the root some thing that would look like `/html/body/div[2]/radiobutton`)
3. To check whether the `ID` for that element has changed, locate the `RadioButton` at that AbsoluteXPath has a different `ID` or not..

Comment: thanks for the hint , i tried on a single element and it worked

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to handle this situation. Since you are trying to fetch an element based on an identifier (let's say ID - Multi), it tries to fetch only that element and since there is no relation to the element that you are searching to the element modified (let's say ID - MultiType).